# Validating email address regular expression with fixed domain

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a email address regular expression that only accepts emails address ending with `"@gbase.tt"`.

I tried: `^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@gbase\.tt$`

Comment: Yours is ok, you just lack the lowercase chars and escaping the `.` at the domain: `^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@gbase\.tt$` - http://regexr.com?35qhk - But you really should use a tool, as your language probably already has it.

Comment: Don't validate email addresses with regular expressions: http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: Yes, don't validate email addresses with regular expressions. The ones that are close to matching all valid cases are overcomplicated and they still don't work as they should be.

Answer (score 5):

Why use a regular expression when you can test if the string ends with "@gbase.tt"?

But if you really must use a regex, try `^.+?@gbase.tt$`.

Comment: I honestly didn't think of testing if the string ends with "@gbase.tt" at first was just editing some code and I wanted to change my previous regular expression to do what I stated above.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with a full regex for email, like the one found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

That expression clearly has the `@` split in it, so keep the first half, and replace  everything after the `@` sign with `gbase\.tt$`.

Keep in mind that you've got to escape the dot since a dot by itself represents any character.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["emailId"].value;
   var atpos=x.indexOf("@abc.com");
   var atpos1=x.indexOf("@xyz.in");
    var atpos2=x.indexOf("@www.in");

if (atpos<1 && atpos1<1 && atpos2<1)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for fixed domain name and email id containing "." or "_"

you can use pattern - pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+(.|_)+[A-Za-z0-9]+@+gmail.com$"

it will only accept email id with domain name gmail.com only